# Resize images using a middleware in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, image-processing

I'm trying a build a REST API where I want to store images. I'm using Node, Express, and MongoDB. Now for storing images, I'm using gridfs, multer because I want to store images in the database.

Now that part is working very well. Here is the code

```
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
url: MongoURL,
file: (req, file) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
      const fileInfo = {
        filename: filename,
        bucketName: 'images'
      };
          resolve(fileInfo);
        });
      });
    }
  });

const upload = multer({ storage });

router.put('/update/profile-picture', checkAuth, 
upload.single('profile_picture'),(req,res) => {
   console.log(req.file);
   res.json('Image Upload');
});
```

I'm not uploading the entire code because the code is very long.

Now before storing the images, I want to compress the images to save space. So I decided to use [jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp)(I'm open to use anything).

So I think I need to use a middleware. So how can I make a middleware that resize and compress the image?

Comment: Maybe you can use `sharp`, it has a toBuffer function maybe use it and make it base64.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using multer with easyimage, it works pretty well but you have to write the file first :

```
const easyimage     = require('easyimage');

app.use(multer({
  dest:       "./public/img",
  limits:     { fileSize: 3* 1024 * 1024}, //3mb
  inMemory:   true
}));


app.use(function(req, res, next){
 // write file

  fs.writeFile( __dirname + "/../" + req.files.file.path, req.files.file.buffer, function(err) {
     return next();
  });

});


app.use(function(req, res, next)[

     easyimage.resize({
        src:            __dirname+"/../"+req.files.file.path,
        dst:            __dirname+"/../"+req.files.file.path,
        width:          640,
        height:         249,
        quality:        100,
        ignoreAspectRatio:  true

    }).then((file) => {

     return next();

    });
});
```